# Date range in query Dynamics AX

Tags: date, range, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to build query Range, where

[image]

ActiveTo < today || ActiveFrom > today.

Is it possible, I tried something like that but it's not working.

```
qbdsDimAttrValue = ds.addDataSource(tableNum(DimensionAttributeValue));
qbrMainAccountActiveFrom = qbdsDimAttrValue.addRange(fieldnum(DimensionAttributeValue,ActiveFrom));
qbrMainAccountActiveFrom.value(strFmt('(((%1.%2 != 0) || (%1.%3 != 0)) && ((%1.%2 > %4) || (%1.%3 < %4)))',   
            qbdsDimAttrValue.name(),
            fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue,ActiveFrom),
            fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue,ActiveTo),
            today(),
            ));
```

I write 0, because in table DimensionAttributeValue if field ActiveFrom, ActiveTo is null it has value 0, not dateNull(), dateMax()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date values used in such queries must be in the `dd\MM\yyyy` format - you can use function `date2StrXpp()` for this purpose.

Try using the following range:

```
qbrMainAccountActiveFrom.value(
    strFmt('((%1.%2 > %4) || ((%1.%3 < %4) && (%1.%3 != %5)))',
            qbdsDimAttrValue.name(),
            fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue, ActiveFrom),
            fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue, ActiveTo),
            date2StrXpp(systemDateGet()),
            date2StrXpp(dateNull())
            ));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check `Global::dateNull()` you will see that it returns '01\01\1900', also you can see that database doesn't store 0 in these fields:
[image]

Yo can find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/null-values-for-data-types)

So you can simplify your extended range as follows

```
qbrMainAccountActiveFrom.value(strFmt('((%1.%2 > %4) || (%1.%3 < %4))',   
                               qbds.name(),
                               fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue, ActiveFrom),
                               fieldStr(DimensionAttributeValue, ActiveTo),
                               today()
                               ));
```

Comment: It won't work for 2 reasons: the ranges are wrong (what if both ActiveFrom and ActiveTo are empty?) and the date is not formatted correctly.